# How do I display data from one mySQL table into multiple tables in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have on mySQL table with data and I want to display it in multiple tables. When I try to do it with the code I have now, the data doesn't show up in the second table. Is my code wrong?

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE room = '{$id}' AND number = '81'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "<center><h2>Room $id</h2></center> <br> <b>General Information<br>     
<table><tr>
<th>Room Type</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>College</th>
<th>Primary Owner</th></tr>";

// output data of each row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row["type"]."</td>
<td>".$row["Department"]."</td>
<td>".$row["College"]."</td>
<td>".$row["Primary"]."</td>
</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";
}

//CONTACT INFO//
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "<p><b>Contact Information<br><table><tr>
<th>Reservations</th>
<th>CTL Contact Name</th>
<th>CTL Contact Email</th>  
<th>CTL Contact Phone</th>
<th>Department Contact Name</th>
<th>Department Contact Email</th>
<th>Department Contact Phone</th>
<th>IT Contact Name</th>
<th>IT Contact Email</th>
<th>IT Contact Phone</th>
</tr>";

// output data of each row

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row["reservations"]."</td>
<td>".$row["contact"]."</td>  
<td>".$row["contactphone"]."</td>
<td>".$row["deptcontact"]."</td>
<td>".$row["deptcontactemail"]."</td>
<td>".$row["deptcontactphone"]."</td>
<td>".$row["itcontact"]."</td>
<td>".$row["itcontactemail"]."</td>
<td>".$row["itcontactphone"]."</td>
</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";
}
else{
echo("0 results"); 
}
```

This is what I get:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2heijyc.png

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: [Protect against SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @salsaverde Please review the answer and mark it as resolved if my answer solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual of **[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**

You've already called `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

This will loop through the entire result array and get each row.  `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns null when there are no more rows.  So the next time you run `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` it will be null.

What you need to do is use **[mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)** at the top to get an array of the result set.  Then you can loop through this array as needed.

---

As I stated in my comment, this query is subject to SQL injections because you use `$id` which is sourced by `$_GET` directly in the query.  Read up on prepared statements or if it is an integer, use `intval($id)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could mysqli_data_seek (  $result , 0 ) to move your pointer back to the first record.

Comment: @BigScar thanks for sharing.  I find it easier to just loop through an array, but it all comes down to personal opinion.  The OP can continue to use *while* with *mysql_fetch_assoc* by using *mysqli_data_seek*.

Comment: Just a couple of ways to skin the same cat.